# conforming to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol

Tags: objective-c

how do you mark your view controller as conforming to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol.

I was told to do this in another post and cant seem to find anywhere how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find This Line in your view controller's .h or .m file:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
```

Add `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` so that that line looks like this:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `.h` or `.m` file, add `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` to the end of the `@interface` line.

Comment: Preferably, it should be done in the `.m` since publicly declaring it to conform to some protocol opens it up to abuse since other objects will be able to set us as the delegate(unless of course that is what you want to do :P ).

Comment: @Unicorn if it doesn't have to be in the .h then it should go in the private interface, along with everything else.